# addClass() a um objeto através de um link externo

Tags: jquery, click, addclass

Preciso criar uma função click() para 8 links que estão em uma `pagina X`, cada link vai me levar para um slide especifico em uma `pagina Y`.

O slide fica ativo quando esta com a Class `selected`, então minha ideia é a seguinte:

O usuário clica no link 1 na pagina X é levado para pagina Y com o slide 1 ativo.

O usuário clica no link 2 na pagina X é levado para pagina Y com o slide 2 ativo.

E por ai vai ...

Então resumindo, como faço para esse addCLass() funcionar após o carregamento da pagina Y.

Caso não tenha ficado muito claro eu edito.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer guardar qual item que receberá a classe nova?

Comment: Eu quero clicar no link 1 e ele adicione uma classe no Slide 1 e por ai vai ... @Laerte

Comment: So que ambos estão em paginas diferentes, link 1 pagina X e slide 1 pagina Y ...  @Laerte

Comment: Ué, passa por parâmetro na URL, a escolha. paginaY?slide=1, paginaY?slide=2

Comment: Se são paginas diferentes tem que ser por url ou com submit.

Answer (score 1):

A ideia que me ocorre é passares no link uma *query string* para poderes analizar na página de chegada qual o slide que deve receber a classe. Por exemplo:

```
<a href="/link?slide=1">Slide 1</a>
<a href="/link?slide=2">Slide 2</a>
```

e na página dos slides:

```
var slide = location.search.match(/slide=(\d+)/)[1];
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides');
slides[slide].classList.add('selected');
```

Isso é o esqueleto. Se precisares de ajuda a implementar diz, posso acrescentar mais detalhes logo quando sair do trabalho.

Comment: usar sessionStorage é uma solução boa também, não?

Comment: @Laerte sim, cookie também daria. Aí é preciso interceptar o redirect para escrever primeiro antes de o browser mudar de página.